# Реализация аутентификации через SMS (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Делаю систему аутентификации на Laravel через SMS. Планирую такой алгоритм:

1. Человек в первой форме регистрации вводит лишь свое имя и телефон
2. Контроллер проверяет, есть ли такой номер телефона в БД, если нет, то идем дальше
3. Генерируем 6-значный код для подтверждения телефона, через сторонний API отсылаем смску на телефон, а также сохраняем данный код в сессию пользователя.
4. На фронте показываем ему следующий экран, т.е. форму ввода кода подтверждения.
5. Человек вводит код, он зарегистрирован (дальше все действия понятны

По этому алгоритму есть несколько вопросов:

1. Правильно ли в пункте 3 сохранять код в сессию пользователя? Или же лучше сделать таблицу в БД с кодами подтверждения, где будут поля "номер телефона-код-действителен до"?
2. Как предотвратить действия злоумышленников (смс-ки платные, поэтому может быть плохо)? Какие есть методы защиты от сброса сессии через очистку браузера и отправки кода подтверждения заново?

Comment: Сохраняете в базу: номер, код и дату отправки. При последующем запросе на отправку сообщения - сверяете дату.

Answer (score 2):

Делать аутентификацию через смс на этапе регистрации (как в п.1 вопроса) смысла нет. Что это вам даёт? Боты вам в лёгкую сольют любой бюджет смс-шлюза (если кому-то это будет надо) за одни сутки регистраций.

Задача много-уровневой аутентификации подтвердить, что в данный момент в личный кабинет заходит именно хозяин аккаунта.

Процесс регистрации логичнее закрывать рекапчами. Вот при попытке входа уже зарегистрированного пользователя пусть вылетает ему на встречу смс с кодом подтверждения. Такой подход обезопасит как хозяина аккаунта от несанкционированного доступа, так и вас от злонамеренных действий, если вдруг у вас зарегистрируется бот с живым номером телефона, и начнёт безостановочно запрашивать смс.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Мне нужна не 2-FA, а именно регистрация по телефону. Т.е. как это сделано, к примеру, на юле, в телеграм и т.д., то есть чтобы у человека от регистрации до момента покупки был лишь 1 шаг.